# What are the best approaches to localizing images with text for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4, localization

I'm planning to localize my iPhone app, including 9 other languages, besides English.

My concern is that I have many `.png` files with texts, with their respectives `@2x` images for the retina display.

Right now my app have 5.6Mb, and I'm afraid that it will be much heavier than that after including the `.png` and `@2x` files for each of the other 9 languages.

From your experience, is that true? Will I end up with a much larger application in size, after localizing it to other 9 languages?

Comment: Why do you keep text as images?

Comment: Just as part of background images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is it depends on how you implemented your app.

If your images contain text, then you'll have to create a new version of these images (both in normal and @2x resolution) for each language. That doesn't just take extra space, it also makes localization very arduous as you'll be spending hours Photoshopping translations into images and managing a ton of files.

Localizable apps typically don't include text in their images, instead they programmatically render text (from the localizable resources) on top of background images. You can use XiBs and overlay `UILabels` over images or other UI elements. If you do this, then you won't have to worry about the size impact of adding languages, and localization will be a breeze.

Comment: I think I can overlay images containing texts on top of backgrounds, for each language, since the bulk of these images are BGs. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this will be an issue.  Assuming that 5MB of your current application is dedicated to your PNG files, then adding 9x to it should make it about 50MB in size.  This isn't a large application.

Other factors that you can consider is that not all images will need to be localized, so even an estimation of 50MB is probably high.

If you are in the middle of writing your application and believe that it will increase to a much larger size, then you may need to consider a different strategy for displaying your text.    Only localize logo files and maybe a few other "fancy" image files.  All of the other text implementations should be implemented through a text layout and formatting engine.

If you absolutely must have your in a text-as-image format, consider rendering the images when the application executes.

One other implementation method (which I have used for other purposes) is to generate all of your graphics and store them without text.  Next, generate separate images files for your text, leaving the background of these images transparent.

When you need to load a specific language image, load the graphical image, first, and then overlay it with the text image.

This will reduce the overall size of your application because the largest PNG files should be those with the most color which you will need only one instance of in your application.  By abstracting the text to another image, you are significantly shrinking the size of the text images.

A word of warning about using this method.  Layering highly transparent or opaque images, over images, over images can get to be pretty intensive on the iOS processor if it is occurring with a high level of frequency. Putting one image on top of another shouldn't be a problem, however, layering many images over one another, in various sections of the display, could bog down your application.  However, if you are just looking for a solution to localize text, I think this one is rather viable.

Comment: I think I can overlay images containing texts on top of backgrounds, for each language, since the bulk of these images are BGs. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

I assumed most of your images will be used for buttons? Instead of creating buttons with Images, consider using a stretchable background image for your buttons, and then add text in it. UIKit provides a lot of methods that can be conveniently used to do calculate and position the text inside buttons.

It's easier to maintain if you do it this way instead of providing images for every single button you have. Also, it gives you room to expand your app in the future without going over 50MB size limitation. Let's say you somehow manage to fit all the stuff in your app and barely under 50MB, what if in the future you're adding some more features or a lot of your users request for a certain language?

I'm sorry if my assumption is wrong. Do let me know so I can amend my answer.

Comment: I think I can overlay images containing texts on top of backgrounds, for each language, since the bulk of these images are BGs. I don't have many different buttons, but mainly BGs. Thanks for your advice!